# Rscript to use renv environment

Tags: r, renv

How do I execute a command using `RScript myfile.R` so that it uses the renv environment of the project/directory it's in, NOT my default environment?

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple ways:

1. Ensure your working directory is set to the root of your `renv` project, and that the renv project's auto-loader is active. (You can set up the auto-loader by calling `renv::activate()` from R in that project.)
2. In your script, explicitly call `renv::load("/path/to/project")` to load the requested project.

If neither of these methods suffice, please file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a similar problem but the answer by @kevin-ushey was insufficient. Here's the background. I need to be able to run `Rscript` from any directory (Because I had several statistical models which were to be called from a Docker file, forcing a Docker file to have `WORKDIR` many times is just too cumbersome when you have long files with several `Rscript` calls. Moreover, some of these models are called several times in different bash files, making it cumbersome to `cd` to the directory before every `Rscript` call). We needed something akin to `conda activate` where any `Rscript` call would just use the activated 'renv environment' by default, regardless of what your working directory is. Here's a dummy example:

1. Install `renv` with `install.packages('renv')`.
2. Create dummy folder with a dummy script containing the `beepr` library (just for the sake of the example) and initialize the `renv` environment:

```sh
mkdir ~/renv_test/
cd ~/renv_test/
echo "library(beepr); print('success')" >> test.R
Rscript -e "renv::init()"
```

3. Create a Docker image with the code below:

```
FROM rocker/r-base

ENV PROJ_ROOT='/usr/local/src/renv_test'
ENV RENV_DIR='/usr/local/.renv/'

COPY . $PROJ_ROOT

# Copy the projects renv infrastructure to RENV_DIR and remove all traces of renv from PROJ_ROOT
RUN mkdir -p $RENV_DIR/renv/ && \
  cp $PROJ_ROOT/renv.lock $RENV_DIR && \
  cp $PROJ_ROOT/renv/activate.R $RENV_DIR/renv/ && \
  echo "source('renv/activate.R')" >> $RENV_DIR/.Rprofile && \
  cd $RENV_DIR && \
  Rscript -e "renv::restore()" && \
  cd $PROJ_ROOT && Rscript -e "renv::deactivate()" && \
  rm -rf renv/ renv.lock

# Set RENV_DIR's restore library as the default library
RUN echo $(cd $RENV_DIR && Rscript -e "cat(paste0('R_LIBS=', renv::paths\$library()), sep = '\n')") >> $HOME/.Renviron


# Run any script from any directory as if you had 'renv activated'
CMD Rscript $PROJ_ROOT/test.R
```

Here's a summary of the approach:

- Copy the project to the docker image
- Copy the `renv` infrastructure to a separate folder (here `~/.renv/`) and restore the project **there**.
- Eliminate all traces of `renv` from the project folder (this is so we don't mess up the path of the library if for some reason we execute a script from the root of this project).
- Edit `.Renviron` so that it contains the restored library path in `~/.renv` as the default library. This ensures that any new R session will use that library as the first option.
- Execute any R scripts located in the project folder without having to `cd` or `WORKDIR` (docker) to the project folder.

If you build and run the previous Docker image, you should get a success statement even though we never `cd` to the project folder:

```sh
docker build -t renv_test .
docker run renv_test
[1] "success"
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe a simpler way than the above answers:

```
Rscript -e 'renv::run("/path/to/myscript.R")'
```

It will pick up the renv environment from the base path. You can also specify the environment using the project parameter.